# How to set the title text color of UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I tried changing the colors of the text for a button, but it's still staying white.

```
isbeauty = UIButton()
isbeauty.setTitle("Buy", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
isbeauty.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColorFromRGB("F21B3F")
isbeauty.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin" , size: 25)
isbeauty.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
isbeauty.layer.cornerRadius = 5
isbeauty.layer.borderWidth = 1
isbeauty.layer.borderColor = UIColorFromRGB("F21B3F").CGColor
isbeauty.frame = CGRectMake(300, 134, 55, 26)
isbeauty.addTarget(self,action: "first:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(isbeauty)
```

I also tried changing it the red, black, blue, but nothing is happening.

Answer (score 359, accepted):

You have to use `func setTitleColor(_ color: UIColor?, for state: UIControl.State)` the same way you set the actual title text. [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623993-settitlecolor)

```
isbeauty.setTitleColor(UIColorFromRGB("F21B3F"), for: .normal)
```

Comment: for readability sake i prefer not to qualify my enums, but thats just me

Comment: @styler1972 I prefer that too - apparently I was unaware of that when I initially wrote the answer

Comment: isbeauty.setTitleColor(UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: "F21B3F"), for: .Normal)

Comment: I believe that as of xcode 9, it's now ".normal" instead of ".Normal"

Comment: my code:
yourButtonName.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)

Comment: If you set the color of the Text in Interface Builder anything but default, it will prevent this method from functioning.

Answer (score 127):

**Swift UI** solution

```
Button(action: {}) {
            Text("Button")
        }.foregroundColor(Color(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0))
```

**Swift 3, Swift 4, Swift 5**

to improve comments.
This should work:

```
button.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 18):

Example in setting button title color

```
btnDone.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
```

Comment: What's the difference between mine answer and yours?

Comment: it's obvious - color

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> func setTitleColor(_ color: UIColor?, 
>                for state: UIControl.State)
> ```

**Parameters**:

> **color:**
>  The color of the title to use for the specified state.
>
> **state:**
>  The state that uses the specified color. The possible values are described in UIControl.State.

**Sample**:

```
let MyButton = UIButton()
MyButton.setTitle("Click Me..!", for: .normal)
MyButton.setTitleColor(.green, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is swift 5 compatible answer. If you want to use one of the built-in colours then you can simply use

```
button.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
```

If you want some custom colours, then create an extension for a UIColor as below first.

```
import UIKit
extension UIColor {
    static var themeMoreButton = UIColor.init(red: 53/255, green: 150/255, blue: 36/255, alpha: 1)
}
```

Then use it for your button as below.

```
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.themeMoreButton, for: .normal)
```

Tip: You can use this method to store custom colours from rgba colour code and reuse it throughout your application.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a button without NSAttribute then you can simply set the title and color of button by using

```
yourButtonName.setTitle("Your Title", for: .normal)

enterCustomAmount.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .normal)
```

but if you give NSAttribute in your button property then you first need to set the attribute for the button

```
var myAttribute = [ NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.init(hexString: "#FFAEA9")]
```

or for more then one property you can use comma separator like

```
var myAttribute = [ NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.init(hexString: "#FFAEA9"), NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Dubai-Medium", size: 16) ]
```

and assign it to your UIButton like this

```
 let myString = "Your title"
            let text = NSAttributedString(string: myString, attributes: myAttribute)
            enterCustomAmount.setAttributedTitle(text, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

referring to radio buttons ,you can also do it with Segmented Control as following:

step 1:
drag a segmented control to your view
in the attribute inspector change the title of the two segments ,for example "Male" and "Female"

step 2:
create an outlet & an action for it in the code

step 3:
create a variable for future use to contain choice's data

in the code do as following:

```
@IBOutlet weak var genderSeg: UISegmentedControl!

var genderPick : String = ""


 @IBAction func segAction(_ sender: Any) {

    if genderSeg.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
         genderPick = "Male"
        print(genderPick)
    } else if genderSeg.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        genderPick = "Female"
          print(genderPick)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***set title color***

```
btnGere.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set UIButton title color with hex code

```
btn.setTitleColor(UIColor(hexString: "#95469F"), for: .normal)
```

Added this extension class to support string color code

```
public extension UIColor {
        convenience init(hexString: String, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) {
            let hexString: String = hexString.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
            let scanner = Scanner(string: hexString)
            
            if (hexString.hasPrefix("#")) {
                scanner.currentIndex = .init(utf16Offset: 1, in: hexString)
            }
            
            var color: UInt64 = 0
            scanner.scanHexInt64(&color)
            let mask = 0x000000FF
            let r = Int(color >> 16) & mask
            let g = Int(color >> 8) & mask
            let b = Int(color) & mask
            let red   = CGFloat(r) / 255.0
            let green = CGFloat(g) / 255.0
            let blue  = CGFloat(b) / 255.0
            
            self.init(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:alpha)
        }
    }
```

Comment: `UIColor` does not provide a `hexString:` initializer.

Comment: This initializer is s extension function.

Answer (score -1):

To change color of text

```
button.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
```

To change state, on button press add following -

```
button.enabled = true
```

IBAction method should be like -

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender : UIButton!) {
    sender.enabled = false
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`continueButton.tintColor = UIColor.white`