# Text color for uilabel not setting

Tags: swift, uibutton

I creating UIButton like that:

```
okBtn = UIButton()
okBtn.setTitle("OK", for: .normal)
okBtn.setTitle("OK", for: .selected)
okBtn.titleLabel?.textColor = .purpleLight
okBtn.backgroundColor = .red
okBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapOKBtn), for: .touchUpInside)
self.addSubview(okBtn)
```

However, color is not setted, i added a screen to show how it looks.

[image]

Comment: use setTitleColor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the title text color of UIButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088172/how-to-set-the-title-text-color-of-uibutton)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `title color`

```
okBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use frame as required & add to your view as -

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let okBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 70, width: 50, height: 50))
    okBtn.setTitle("OK", for: .normal)
    okBtn.backgroundColor = .red
    okBtn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    view.addSubview(okBtn)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the frame size first.

```
    okBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100)) //Sets the frame size on your viewController
    okBtn.setTitle("OK", for: .normal)
    okBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.purple, for: .normal) //Sets the color of the text on the button
    //There is no color as purpleLight. You need to set the rgb to get your desired color.
    okBtn.backgroundColor = .red
    okBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapOKBtn), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(okBtn)
```