# How can I change text color on an input?

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a script to allow users to change element colors.

The script is designed to work on the text in buttons.

I have tried this:

```
func prettyText(_ button: RoundButton, colour: UIColor) {

   button.textColor = colour

}
```

but it gives this error:

> Value of type 'RoundButton' has no member 'textColor'; did you mean 'tintColor'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the title text color of UIButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088172/how-to-set-the-title-text-color-of-uibutton)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIButton` has [setTitleColor(_:for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623993-settitlecolor) method. So in your case

```
func prettyText(_ button: RoundButton, colour: UIColor) {
    button.setTitleColor(colour, for: .normal)
}
```